# NestJS Handle status code 500 and response body

Tags: nestjs

I know NestJS handle all the status code who are different from 200-299 as an error, and I already created my own `HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter` to handle errors.

Well, this is my current scenario. One of my providers is sending me the response with status code 500 in case a value is wrong (not a real server error), but in the response it comes the message and description.

Is there a way to catch `inline` the exception without transfer the response to my `ExceptionFilter`?

```
const options = {
      requestBody,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer 12345`,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      },
      data: requestBody,
    };


    const endpoint = http://myclientendpoint.com;

    try {
      const response = await this.httpService
        .post(endpoint, requestBody, options)
        .toPromise();
      if (
        response == null ||
        response == undefined ||
        response.data == null ||
        response.data == undefined
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      console.log(response.data);

      return await response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('>>> THIS IS TRIGGERED WITHOUT THE RESPONSE BODY');
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible adding a `try catch` and getting the body content with: `error.response.data`

This is the example:

```
try {
      const response = await this.httpService
        .post(endpoint, requestBody, options)
        .toPromise();
      if (
        response == null ||
        response == undefined ||
        response.data == null ||
        response.data == undefined
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      console.log(response.data); 

      return await response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 500) {
        console.log('> TRYING TO HANDLED 500 status code');
        console.log(error.response.data);
        return error.response.data;
      }
      if (error.response.status === 403) {
        console.log('> TRYING TO HANDLED 403 status code');
        console.log(error.response.data);
        return error.response.data;
      }
      if (error.response.status === 505) {
        console.log('> TRYING TO HANDLED 505 status code');
        console.log(error.response.data);
        return error.response.data;
      }

      console.log(error);

      return null;
    }
```